# Retrieve all or children organization units using Google Client Library

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-api-python-client

How to retrieve all organisation units in a google apps domain using google client library ? Which function we need to use to retrive the OrgUnits in google client library ?

I didn't find any documentation on [gdata-python-client site](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/)

```
def create_service():
    f = file(API_DATA["SERVICE_PEM_PATH"], 'rb')
    key = f.read()
    f.close()

    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(API_DATA["SERVICE_EMAIL"], key, scope=API_DATA["DIRECTORY_SCOPES"], sub=API_DATA["ADMIN_EMAIL"])
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    service = build("admin", "directory_v1", http=http)
    return service


directory = create_service()

# directory.RetrieveAllOrganizationUsers() -- Function to retrieve Org Units ??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an API method dedicated to this : `orgunits.list`.

[The reference documentation is here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/list).

[The Python library documentation is here](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.orgunits.html#list).

I am not an expert in python, but I expect the call to look like this :

```
directory.orgunits().list(customerId='my_customer').execute()
```

By the was this is not a GData API, that's why you did not find info there. GData is the name of the old format of APIs, that Google is progressively deprecating.